# How do i use the answer of one of my variables to store more information in another variable

Tags: python, loops, variables

This is my code

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t']
  while a is not '':
    b = b + 1
    d = c[b]
    row = input('Enter row')
```

I am trying to get it so that instead of the information being stored in the variable row, it is stored in the answer of the variable d.

So say if the variable b is 5, the variable d will get the sixth string in the list c, which is 'f'. I then want 'f' to be the variable name instead of 'row'

Comment: I recommend adding the program language you are using to your tag list. ie Python. This will help the appropriate developers to find your question. Also, it is not clear to me what you are asking. Perhaps you could rephrase the question or add some more detail?

Comment: @C0D3R can you update your expected output?

Comment: @ramesh im sorry i don't really understand what you mean

Comment: @C0D3RM4DN3SS how exactly you want to your output and how exactly it looks like